# how do I split a column into seperate columns in a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm working on a movie genre data set and the dataset has all the genres in a single column but I want to split them.

here's how the data set looks like:

```
   genres
----------------------------------------------
   [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
   [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
   [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
   [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
   [{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
```

So what I want to do is get only the first genre so the new column should look like:

```
  genres
_____________
  Animation
  Comedy
  Comedy
  Comedy
  Action
```

[image]

I hope this is clear enough to understand my problem.

Comment: what have you tried?  do you care about the genre `id`?  does the actual CSV file following standard escaping rules?  i.e. could you post a few lines of the actual data so people have a chance of providing a useful answer

Comment: Is your source data shown above is in a file or a dataframe? Same question goes with your expected result (as I see pipe in your expected result)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).
 The first dictionary in the list is selected in each cell. From that dictionary the `name` field is selected:

```
df['genres']=df['genres'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['name'])
print(df)
```

---

```
   ID     genres
0   0  Animation
1   1     Comedy
2   2     Comedy
3   3     Comedy
4   4     Action
```

---

or

```
df['genres']=df['genres'].apply(lambda x: eval(x)[0]['name'])
```

---

> TRY THIS

```
def decode_str_dict(x):
    try:
        out=eval(x)[0]['name']
    except Exception:
        try:
            out=eval(x)['name']
        except Exception:
            try:
                out=eval(x)
            except Exception:
                out=x
    return out



df['genres'].apply(decode_str_dict)
```

Comment: but I got an error as the indices should be integers

Comment: What type of data does the index of your DataFrame have?

Comment: I think you need `astype(object)` or use reset_index

Comment: So the solution is correct ?. If you want you can update the question and I can help you finish solving your problem

Comment: Do you have a dataframe or a series?. Do you access the data using df ['genre'] or directly by the name of the series?

Comment: can you show in your answer the output of `df.index`?

Comment: Have you trayed my solution with eval?

Comment: I've added a screenshot please have a look

Comment: What is the output of `type(df['genres'][0])`?

Comment: I wanted to say: `type(df['genres'][0])` forget the end s, check if 'genres' is in `df.columns`

Comment: then you need eval, but i dont know why list out of range....

Comment: `df['genres'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))` get an error?

Comment: then `type(df['genres'].apply(lambda x: eval(x))[i])` must be 'list' for all i, 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: I think that in some cell there may not be a list of dictionaries and that is why for that cell you cannot select eval (x) [0] because that cell does not contain a list. I think that is the error

Comment: so how should i fix it ? the ones which are not list ? how can i delete that ?

Comment: i update a solution for it. 
It may not work perfectly, it depends on all possible cases that occur in the cell. That code must be executed without errors. Please attach me a photo of the output of this code or copy and paste the output in your response

Answer (score 3):

```
df['genres'] = df['genres'].map(lambda x:[i['name'] for i in x])
df['first_genre'] = df['genres'][0]
df = df[['name','first_genre']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I got an error as "string indices must be integers"

Answer (score 3):

This works if the values are considered a string.

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['genres'] = df.genres.map(lambda x: literal_eval(x)[0]['name'])
```

Result:

```
Out[294]: 
  ID     genres
1  0  Animation
2  1     Comedy
3  2     Comedy
4  3     Comedy
5  4     Action
```

Comment: try just `df['genres] = df.genres.map(lambda x: literal_eval(x))` and then use ansev solution.